# Upgrade Youtube Feeds API2 to API3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, feed, youtube-data-api

I have two deprecated youtube-API-v2 feeds. Someone can help me to upgrade these lines to the new YT-API-3?

1)

`$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq={$vq}&orderby={$s}&max-results={$i}&start-index={$o}&lr={$l}&key=xxxxx"`;

2)

```
var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=" + this.searchTerm + "+music&alt=json&orderby=relevance&start-index=" + this.offset + "&max-results=" + this.maxResults + "&v=2";
```

Comment: Could you supply a sample code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Solution from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/339idg/youtube_just_dropped_its_support_for_rssatom_feeds/) post

Partial false alarm! /u/foreander has a solution:

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNELID
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USERNAME

Unlike the v2 endpoints, this one is severely rate-limited. Query it more than a few times in a row and you'll start getting empty responses.

They offer an OPML file with all your subscriptions in it as separate feeds under http://youtube.com/subscription_manager?action_takeout=1